# Where Does SYMBOL TABLE Reside?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I wanted to know where does SYMBOL TABLE reside. Is it in `.obj` files or an `.exe` file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another similar [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112/what-is-a-symbol-table).  In the answers to this question, it mentions that the symbol table is in each .obj file.

Comment: zooropa, Thank you very much :).

Comment: You're welcome!  Thanks for the reputation points on my birthday!