# What is a good resource to read about stack/heap and symbol table concepts?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, callstack, heap-memory

Please suggest some website or some book that deals with these topics in really good detail.

I need to have a better understanding of these concepts (in reference to C++):

1. stack and heaps
2. symbol tables
3. implementation of scope rules
4. implementation of function calls

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: Also, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112/what-is-a-symbol-table

Comment: Are you writing a C++ compiler?  Or are you trying to learn the C++ language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the [Dragon Book](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/), but I guess it might be too much.

Answer (score 2):

For calling functions, this Wikipedia page is great: [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) - it explains the various ways to translate function calls to assembly.

Also, this Wikibook on [x86 Disassembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly), has some interesting pages on this topic:

- [The stack](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack)
- [Calling convention examples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Convention_Examples)

Answer (score 1):

Try [online version](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) of the "[Linkers &Loaders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960)" book.  [Chapter 11](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker11.html) may help you with these concepts w.r.t C++. A very good book to get your fundamentals right. Try Gustavo's [excellent blog](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory) to understand concepts of memory management ([stack, heap](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory) and a lot more).

Comment: Gustavo's blog is the most excellent piece of technical explanation I've seen to date. Esp. when it's in an area that is full of jargon. Clarity, simplicity and detail with superb pictures. Simply amazing.  Note: The Dragon book is not the best place to grasp these concepts, even for intermediate programmers.