# Symbol Table created by the C++ compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, symbols, effective-c++

I was reading *Effective C++*, 3rd edition and in item 2 (*prefer const, enums, and inlines to #defines*), Scott Meyers mentions the **symbol table**: he explains that `#defines` may not appear in the *symbol table*.

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169/1244630), a bit of the suggested [reading](http://net.gurus.org/toc-linker.html) thereof, and the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) article, I would define the symbol table as follows: since the compiler only creates object files for every translation unit, we still need a way to reference symbols between the translation units. This is done using a table that is created for every object file so that symbols can be defined at a later stage - by the linker when the executable/library is created from the object files. During linking, symbols are substitutes with their appropriate memory addresses by the linker.

Here's what I'd like to know:

- Is my interpretation above correct?
- After linking, once the memory addresses have been resolved, I don't think that symbol tables are required? That is, I think that the symbol table won't be available in the executable/library; is that correct?
- I suspect that the symbol table is also useful for other compiler tasks? Something like identifying naming conflicts perhaps?
- The symbol table described above is not the same as the [export table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx). In the context of Visual C++ at least, the export table defines the symbols that are explicitly declared as visible outside of the library. I suppose in a sense this is a table of symbols - but not related to the symbol table Scott is referring to.
- Is there anything else that's interesting about the symbol table? That is, is there any additional insight about symbol tables that I ought to have?

Thank you for your time and contribution.

Answer (score 6):

Symbol tables exist both for the compiler (and then the compiler puts even local variable symbols in them; even the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) has some sort of symbol tables for `#define`-d names, but the preprocessor might be inside the compiler today) and for the linker. But these are different tables, organized differently.

The linker symbol table is mostly for exported or imported global symbols. Be aware that the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) performs some [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29). Be aware that the linker is behaving quite differently on Windows and on Linux (`dllimport` on Windows, `__attribute__(visibility...)` on Linux). Notice that for dynamic libraries, some linking happens at runtime ([dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading)). For C++, [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) can happen. Read also about [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html#Vague-Linkage) & [template instantiation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html) & [link-time optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...

Read also [Levine's book: *Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) and e.g. the wikipage on the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format (used for object files, shared libraries and executables on Linux and many Unix systems).

If you have access to some Linux system, use the [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) and [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) utilities. Read also [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (on Linux)